# At what point in time for a tradition being considered a tradition within Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, reference-request, time

**What is the gold mark or point in time for a tradition being considered a tradition within Catholicism?**

This question is very similar to the question: [When does a tradition become a Tradition?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44765/when-does-a-tradition-become-a-tradition)

This question will simply deal with time frames for declaring a tradition as a recognized tradition within the Catholic Church? Is it 50 years, 100 years, 200 years or something else?

In the Hebrew Bible, [forty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/40_(number)) is often used for time periods, forty days or forty years, which separate "two distinct epochs".

The fiftieth (50) is associated very closely to the duration in time for the [Biblical Jubilee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_(biblical)).

The one hundredth mark seems to be the logical mark that a tradition would be considered a an established tradition. In fact this is the point in time I was taught when younger, but I have not found a reference indicating one way or another if it is valid.

Is 200 years the golden mark? On 14 July 1570, Pope St. Pius V promulgated [***Quo Primum***](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius05/p5quopri.htm), abrogating rites less than 200 years old:

> This new rite alone [the Tridentine Liturgy] is to be used unless approval of the practice of saying Mass differently was given at the very time of the institution and confirmation of the church by Apostolic See at least 200 years ago, or unless there has prevailed a custom of a similar kind which has been continuously followed for a period of not less than 200 years, in which most cases We in no wise rescind their above-mentioned prerogative or custom.

My present question was curiously inspired by Peter Turner’s post: [Does ***Traditionis Custodes*** have any effect on Novus Ordo mass?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84278/does-traditionis-custodes-have-any-effect-on-novus-ordo-mass)

It could be noted that [***Taditionis Custodes***](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html) is curiously timed for the 1970's 50th anniversary of ***lex orandi***. Is 50 years the golden number for a stable recognized tradition?

Thus can anyone reference what the Catholic Church uses as a time qualification duration for establishing tradition as such?

Comment: I'm not sure how your question is different from the one you reference.

Comment: The purpose of the quoted reference is to distance the Catholic rite(s) from those of pre-Reformers, such as Jan Hus; not sure why you'd take it as implying a philosophical or universal statement about some minimum required age for something to be regarded as tradition (!).